# Laravel, Especificar la columna de validacion en Rule::exists('mytable,myid')

Tags: php, laravel, exists, rules

How can I specify the validation column in the rule exists. My table is called "tables"
I have this code in my controller:

```php
'table_id' => [
    'required', 
    Rule::exists('tables')->where(function($query) use($request){                        
        $query->where('id', $request->table_id)->whereNull('deleted_at');
    }),
]
```

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'table_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tables` where `table_id` = 200 and (`id` = 200 and `deleted_at` is null))

Comment: English on Stackoverflow please :)

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You're missing a closing `'` on `'required, `, but I think that's a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 0):

'table_id' => [
'required',
Rule::exists('tables',**'columnName'**)->where(function($query) use($request){
$query->where('id', $request->table_id)->whereNull('deleted_at');
}),
]

inside the exists(), you can pass other parameters, like the connection or the column